# jquery get background image response location

Tags: jquery

I am loading in some images from facebook as backgorund images for divs on my website. Due to permissions some images are not loaded and facebook returns static default image of blue question mark. I want to replace it with my default picture, however I can't find a way to detect this. 
Dom elements are not updated if response url location does not match requests, so there is no way to select it with jquery selectors. I need to find a way to catch all image requests and then check one by one their responses but I am not able to find a working solution.
Any help would be welcome.

Comment: You'll probably have to load all images through your own server. I suppose Facebooks sends a status code with the forbidden images, you can't read that client side(for images on other domains) but server side should be ok.

Comment: There might also be some solution loading the image to canvas(not sure it is allowed for external images) and test several pixels if they match the default.